# Dynamic linking in zOS

Tags: dynamic-linking, zos

i have to create a dynamically linked library in zOS . What are the options to be passed to the compiler.

Also, how to check if a library in zOS is dynamically linked[dependent] on other libraries.
we have ldd in linux, which shows this linkage. Do we have a 'ldd' equivalent in zOS land?

Comment: Have you checked out [Building and using Dynamic Link Libraries](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r10.cbcpx01/dllsim.htm)?

Comment: Yes. I have modified the build scripts to create dynamically link the libraries..looking for a tool to validate the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say it directly, but I assume you mean a C/C++ DLL. You can do shared libraries in other languages as well (even assembler), but the steps would be different.

First, you need to decide what you want to export. A lot of the IBM examples use the compiler EXPORTALL directive, but be aware this can lead to very slow executables, depending on your coding style. If you don't do EXPORTALL, you'll need #pragma export for anything (code or data) you want to export. Don't forget you can export data (variables) as well as executable functions...sometimes you'll need this to share data with DLL functions.

Then, you need to set your compile options on *both* client (caller) and DLL to use the DLL linkage...this is the -Wc,DLL compile option and when enabled, it generates extra logic in your program to load and manage the DLL. It's a good idea to also include #pragma csect for your exported functions if you think you'll ever have the need to update the DLL without replacing it entirely.

When you link your DLL, be sure to specify the -Wl,DLL option (there are lots of ways...this part is different if you link in batch - I'm assuming you're building in a make file of some sort). The link will generate the actual DLL, as well as a "side deck" containing "IMPORT" statements for all of your exported functions. You'll need these to link any of the client-side programs that you expect to call the DLL. For example, if your imports are in a file called AAA.x, c89 -Wc,DLL myapp.c AAA.x would compile the calling code, with awareness that functions in AAA.x are off in some sort of DLL.

To your point about DLLs calling other DLLs, don't forget that a DLL can both "serve" and "consume" functions...by including the side deck for functions in other DLLs, you can have a DLL that provides some functions while calling other DLLs to access others.

The actual DLL itself can be in several places depending on the nature of your app. If you're UNIX Services friendly, it's just an executable in LIBPATH. It can also be STEPLIB, LNKLST, LPA and so forth.

If you need to, you can access your DLLs explicitly at runtime using dlopen(), dlsym() and so forth. Generally, this lets you control exactly which DLL you're using (sometimes handy if the user can provide one himself), and it gives you what amounts to function pointers that are resolved within the DLL.

There are some other basic things to consider when linking, such as ensuring that your code is reentrant. Most of these are spelled out in the IBM documentation, and if you build with things like "c89" (or equivalent), the correct options are usually setup for you automatically (in fact, to get a good idea of what's going on, turn on the verbose output and see all the parameters for yourself).

If you need to build up a cross reference of what calls what, the UNIX Services "nm" command can give you that information. If you produce detailed link-edit listings, all the data is in there too when you're building your DLLs.

Good luck!